# Calculate the closest point given 6 of latitude and longitude points

Tags: geometry

We are having to solve the following problem. Give six geographic latitude and longitude values, we need to calculate the closest point to all the six locations. Can you please suggest the approaches that could be taken to get the result with minimum error?

Answer (score 0):

*First time in my life working with longitude and latitude coordinates.*

If you look [here](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/), you will find approximations for converting to distances (under a few assumptions).

So, let $(X,Y)$ being the longitude and latitude of the unknown point and $(x_i,y_i)$ the longitude and latitude of the known points.

So, applying the formulae given in the link, you are able to compute the distance between the unknown point and each of the known points; let us call it $d_i$.

So, now you need to minimize $\max(d_i)$ varying $(X,Y)$. This is a minimization problem. Probaly, a search on a grid will allow to locate the point. Zooming and repeating could work.

Have also a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula); it could be very helpful.

Good luck !

the known points.